# T-SQL sp_msforeachdb problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to compare the database name using the `?` operator in the `sp_msforeachdb` function.  Here is a snippet:

```
EXEC master..sp_msforeachdb '

USE [?];
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT db_name(database_id) as [database] 
    FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys 
    WHERE [Database] = ''?'')
BEGIN
...
'
```

Basically, I want to be able to find the databases that do not have an encryption key and begin/end a transaction ELSE begin/end a different transaction.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use this procedure - it's undocumented, unsupported, and has a known bug that will not be fixed (it skips databases). See https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb, https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior, and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: I see your solution on mssqltips.com and on your blog (sqlblog.com), and I respect you a great deal as an author, forum answering guru, and all-round great guy... but when the ???? is Microsoft actually going to build in some supported native functions for this?  This is a common task.

Comment: @PromethusRising Since a well-publicized workaround exists, and since people are moving away from black boxes like this and opting for more scalable approaches like PowerShell anyway, they're not.

Comment: In my experience sp_msforeachdb fails on very long database names, including the "long_name_plus_a_big_GUID" style which are commonly found on MS SharePoint installations.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no [Database] column in sys.dm_database_encryoption_keys, and in your WHERE clause, you cannot use an alias name in the SELECT list because WHERE clause is parsed earlier than the SELECT clause by the database engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` stands for the datbase name and `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` holds `database_id`.

```
exec master..sp_msforeachdb
'
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT  null
    FROM    [?].sys.dm_database_encryption_keys 
    WHERE   database_id = db_id(''?'')
)
BEGIN
    print ''?''
END
'
```

Comment: This fixes the issue with `?` being a name rather than a number, but this still leaves a very large problem just waiting to bite people. I would strongly recommend against ever using this procedure for anything you want to even remotely rely on.